# <mariadb has no attribute Error> no python/windows

Tags: python, windows, mariadb

Olá,

Estou tentando utilizar o mariadb com python no windows.

Meu sistema é:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.6rc1
- pip 20.2.3

Instalei o conector:

- download [mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.0-win64.msi](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.1.0/)

E instalei o mariadb:

- pip3 install mariadb

Ao executar o script abaixo:

```
import mariadb
import sys

config = {
    'host'     : 'localhost',
    'user'     : 'root',
    'password' : 'password'
}

try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(**config, database='database')
except mariadb.Error as err:
    print(err, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SHOW TABLES")
for (tbl,) in cur.fetchall(): # pre-fetch all data to free up the cursor
    print("\n===", tbl, "===\n")
    cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{tbl}`")
    print([x[0] for x in cur.description]) # print field names (as a list)
    for row in cur: # using an iterator minimizes the memory used
        print(row) # print every row in this table (each as a tuple)

#~ cur.execute("INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    #~ (1, "A 'string' with single quotes.", '2020-01-01'))

conn.close()
```

Aparece esta mensagem de erro:

```
>pythonw -u "mariadb.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\teste\mariadb.py", line 17, in <module>
    conn = mariadb.connect(**config, database='database')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'mariadb' has no attribute 'connect' (most likely due to a circular import)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mariadb.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mariadb
  File "E:\teste\mariadb.py", line 18, in <module>
    except mariadb.Error as err:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'mariadb' has no attribute 'Error' (most likely due to a circular import)
>Exit code: 1    Time: 0.1065
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais os cuidados que devo tomar ao nomear um arquivo em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478558/quais-os-cuidados-que-devo-tomar-ao-nomear-um-arquivo-em-python)

Answer (score 2):

Você criou um arquivo com o mesmo nome que a biblioteca. Sendo assim, você está importando seu próprio arquivo, ao invés de importar a biblioteca `mariadb`.

A solução é renomear seu arquivo `mariadb.py` para qualquer outro nome.

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado!