# Quais os cuidados que devo tomar ao nomear um arquivo em Python?

Tags: python, convenções-de-nome

É bastante comum vermos problemas gerados porque o arquivo em Python foi nomeado com o mesmo nome de uma biblioteca.

```py
# requests.py

import requests

response = requests.get(...)
```

Esse trecho de código geraria o erro:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

Sendo assim, quais são todos os cuidados que devo tomar ao nomear um arquivo em Python e por quê?

Comment: A ideia da pergunta é gerar uma resposta canônica sobre o assunto, dado que muitos usuários tem problemas com isso.

Comment: Esse problema é recorrente tanto na versão 2 como a 3?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sim, mas a mensagem de erro muda.

Answer (score 1):

Clique neste link, procure o tema "Convenções de Nomenclatura" e você poderá esclarecer todas as suas dúvidas sobre nomenclatura de arquivos (módulos), classes, métodos, variáveis, etc.

[Veja: Convenções de Nomenclatura Python - PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)

Resumo (copiado):

**Convenções de Nomenclatura**

**Nomes a evitar**
Nunca use os caracteres 'l' (letra "L" minúscula), 'O' (letra "o" maiúscula) ou 'I' (letra "i" maiúscula) como nomes de variáveis ​​de caractere único.

Em algumas fontes, esses caracteres são indistinguíveis dos numerais um (1) e zero (0). Quando for tentado a usar 'l', use 'L'.

**Compatibilidade ASCII**
Os identificadores usados ​​na biblioteca padrão devem ser compatíveis com ASCII, conforme descrito na seção de política do PEP 3131 .

**Nomes de pacotes e módulos**
Os módulos devem ter nomes curtos, todos em minúsculas. Sublinhados podem ser usados ​​no nome do módulo se melhorar a legibilidade. Os pacotes Python também devem ter nomes curtos, todos em minúsculas, embora o uso de sublinhados seja desencorajado.

Quando um módulo de extensão escrito em C ou C++ tem um módulo Python acompanhante que fornece uma interface de nível superior (por exemplo, mais orientada a objetos), o módulo C/C++ tem um sublinhado inicial (por exemplo, _socket).

**Nomes de classes**
Nomes de classes normalmente devem usar a convenção CapWords (CamelCase).

A convenção de nomenclatura para funções pode ser usada nos casos em que a interface é documentada e usada principalmente como um callable.

Observe que há uma convenção separada para nomes embutidos: a maioria dos nomes embutidos são palavras únicas (ou duas palavras executadas juntas), com a convenção CapWords usada apenas para nomes de exceção e constantes embutidas.

**Nomes de variáveis ​​de tipo**
Nomes de variáveis ​​de tipo introduzidos no PEP 484 devem normalmente usar CapWords preferindo nomes curtos: T, AnyStr, Num. Recomenda-se adicionar sufixos _co ou _contra às variáveis ​​usadas para declarar o comportamento covariante ou contravariante de forma correspondente.

**Nomes de exceção**
Como as exceções devem ser classes, a convenção de nomenclatura de classe se aplica aqui. No entanto, você deve usar o sufixo "Erro" em seus nomes de exceção (se a exceção realmente for um erro).

**Nomes de Variáveis ​​Globais**
(Esperemos que essas variáveis ​​sejam destinadas ao uso em apenas um módulo)
As convenções são quase as mesmas que as das funções.
Módulos que são projetados para uso por meio de import * devem usar o mecanismo **all** para evitar a exportação de globais ou usar a convenção mais antiga de prefixar esses globais com um sublinhado (o que você pode querer fazer para indicar que esses globais são "módulo não público").

**Nomes de funções e variáveis**
Os nomes das funções devem estar em letras minúsculas, com palavras separadas por sublinhados conforme necessário para melhorar a legibilidade.

**Os nomes das variáveis ​​seguem a mesma convenção dos nomes das funções.**

MixedCase é permitido apenas em contextos onde esse já é o estilo predominante (por exemplo, threading.py), para manter a compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

**Argumentos de função e método**
*Sempre use self como o primeiro argumento para métodos de instância.*

*Sempre use cls para o primeiro argumento para métodos de classe.*

Se o nome de um argumento de função conflitar com uma palavra-chave reservada, geralmente é melhor anexar um único sublinhado final em vez de usar uma abreviatura ou erro ortográfico. Portanto, class_ é melhor do que clss. (Talvez seja melhor evitar esses confrontos usando um sinônimo.)

**Nomes de métodos e variáveis ​​de instância**
Use as regras de nomenclatura de função: minúsculas com palavras separadas por sublinhados conforme necessário para melhorar a legibilidade.

Use um sublinhado inicial apenas para métodos não públicos e variáveis ​​de instância.

Para evitar conflitos de nome com subclasses, use dois sublinhados iniciais para invocar as regras de mutilação de nome do Python.

Python confunde esses nomes com o nome da classe: se a classe Foo tem um atributo denominado __a, ela não pode ser acessada por Foo.__a. (Um usuário insistente ainda pode obter acesso chamando Foo._Foo__a). Geralmente, sublinhados à esquerda duplos devem ser usados ​​apenas para evitar conflitos de nome com atributos em classes projetadas para serem subclasses.

Nota: há alguma controvérsia sobre o uso de __names.

**Constantes**
As constantes são geralmente definidas em um nível de módulo e escritas em letras maiúsculas com sublinhados separando as palavras. Os exemplos incluem MAX_OVERFLOW e TOTAL.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Se viu o meu comentário na pergunta, deve ter visto que a ideia é gerar uma resposta canônica. Se o link que citou responde de forma completa, poderia transcrever o conteúdo para cá? E se o nome possuir espaços em branco? É válido, mas quais as implicações? E se o nome do arquivo for igual ao de outra biblioteca? O que acontece?

Comment: Eu fiz um resumo das recomendações, mas quem desejar se aprofundar no tema poderá consultar as recomendações PEP8. Não é muito inteligente repetir material já publicado que pode ser obtido apenas clicando em um link.

Answer (score 0):

Ao nomear um arquivo, ou seja, um **módulo**, o programador deve atentar-se ao nome propriamente dito e à sua forma.

O nome do módulo **NÃO DEVE** ter o mesmo nome de uma biblioteca que será usada no seu programa pelo fato descrito na pergunta.

Já a forma do nome, deve seguir a [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) que diz que nome de módulos devem usar letra minúscula, serem curtos e podem usar *underscore* (`_`) caso melhore na leitura do nome. Por outro lado, nomes de pacotes seguem a mesma regra, mas o uso de *underscore* é desencorajado.

Meus primeiros *two cents*. Conheça as bibliotecas que vc irá usar em seu projeto e **NUNCA** use o nomeie os módulos e pacotes de seu projeto com o nome destas bibliotecas.

**PORÉM**, se você gosta de viver perigosamente, ou faz malabarismo, acrobacias, ou se "não bate bem da cachola" (risos), sempre tem um jeito.

1. Instale a biblioteca `requests` (pip install requests)
2. Crie um módulo (arquivo) com o nome de `requests.py` com o conteúdo abaixo

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://www.google.com)

print(responses)
```

3. Execute o arquivo com `python requests.py`

Você receberá uma mensagem como a abaixo:

> AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

4. Agora prepare-se para seu *duplo twist carpado* modificando o arquivo para.

```
import importlib.util
import sys

module_name = "requests"
file_path = "/caminho/para/a/biblioteca/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py"

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

import requests

response = requests.get("http://www.google.com")

print(response)
```

5. A resposta será

> <Response [200]>

**Nota**: Perceba que você pode atribuir QUALQUER nome para `module_name`, logo se você fizer um *triplo mortal esticado com quinze piruetas* você poderá fazer o abaixo

```
import importlib.util
import sys

module_name = "QUALQUER"
file_path = "/caminho/para/a/biblioteca/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py"

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

import QUALQUER

response = QUALQUER.get("http://www.google.com")

print(response)
```

6. A resposta será

> <Response [200]>

Se vc foi audacioso a ponto de tentar isso tudo, parabéns. Mas deixo meus últimos *two cents*

**SE QUISER FAZER PARA BRINCAR, TUDO BEM... MAS POR FAVOR NÃO FAÇA ISSO EM UM PROJETO DE VERDADE**