# Qual o estilo apropriado para escrever em Python?

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação

Qual o padrão para nomear classes, métodos, variáveis, etc., em Python, eu achava que assim como em Java era o CamelCase, mas recentemente ouvi dizer para usar o snake_case. Existe algum padrão especifico em Python? Qual desses dois é melhor de se usar?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478558/quais-os-cuidados-que-devo-tomar-ao-nomear-um-arquivo-em-python) tem relação com sua pergunta

Comment: Veja em: [Post com o mesmo tema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478558/quais-os-cuidados-que-devo-tomar-ao-nomear-um-arquivo-em-python/497248#497248)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso está [documentando na PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id34). Basicamente diz para usar o padrão `snake_case`, ou seja, escrever tudo em minúsculo e palavras são separadas com um *underline*.

Isso vale para quase todos os identificadores, exceto constantes que sugere-se usar `ALL_CAPS`, que só muda que tudo é maiúsculo. E nomes de classes devem seguir o estilo `PascalCase`, portanto todas palavras devem apenas começar com maiúscula, o resto é minúscula. Parece que exceções também, mas aí já entramos em [guia da Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#316-naming).

Nem todos seguem a recomendação oficial. O mais importante é ser consistente depois que escolhe porém se a linguagem escolheu uma forma se você escolher outra começará aparecer inconsistências. Tem gente que pode achar isso bom para indicar melhor o que é código seu, mas não acho bom.